# How to set margin/padding for a device

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive

Im making my website responsive for devices but i want to know if i can set a grid or margin/padding property for iphone so i can place it nicely and not 2 paragraphs in eachother.

I already tried to grid some text but it still looks weird in eachother this is my code:

```
            <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-1 col-lg-12">
                <a href="#" class="test navbar-brand">Thisismy Test</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: when you say 2 paragraphs.. do you want the text in 2 seperate paragaraphs side by side or every thing in a row .. one after the other ???

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tagged this as being a Bootstrap grid, but I'm assuming it is because of your grid classes.

You mention that you want to stop the navbar-brand text from wrapping on an iPhone so I'm wondering if there's there a reason why you wouldn't make the navbar-brand parent wider?

It looks to me as if it would need to be minimum `col-xs-5`

Here's a example showing both your existing HTML and the modification 
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/OgQxBw

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-5 col-lg-12">
    <a href="#" class="test navbar-brand">Thisismy Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the paragraph in entire row in mobile , use col-xs-12 class which will occupy the entire row space and display everything in one row in all th escreen sizes.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <a href="#" class="test navbar-brand">Thisismy Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to display 2 paragraphs in row side by side use col-xs-6 for each div

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-12">
    <a href="#" class="test navbar-brand">Thisismy Test</a>
  </div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-12">
    <a href="#" class="test navbar-brand">Thisismy Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want to write your own CSS , you can do that by using media queries to define custom CSS for different screen sizes https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: yes im using now media queries but i really want to know if i need to make like for each max-width? Cuz i have a 1920x1080 monitor do i need to make each monitor a media querie?

Comment: @Choori02 u don't need to specify breakpoints for every size . unless u really want to ... u can define some common breakpoints for every screensize .. this link might help you with defining break points.. https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/

Comment: But i mean do i need to do every new screen resolution a media querie?

Comment: @Choori02 for example if u define a media-querie media (max-width:460px) this will cover all the devices who screeen resolution is leass than that , media(min-width:1024px) should cover all the displays. You have to generalize the CSS based on breakpoints. My case i will define breakpoints at 320px, 480px, 760px, 1024px.

Comment: In the above comment replace media with @media

Comment: So i can get my code on different devices (resolutions) in 1 media querie?

Comment: @Choori02 media(max-width : 768px) should cover all the mobile devices.

Comment: how can i cover all the monitor devices? Like laptop/computer

Comment: Cuz first i did like @media screen only and (max-width: 1920px) but that is only covering 1920x1080 resolutions

Comment: @Choori02 media(min-width:960px) should cover all the monitors .... not just 960px and value should work for monitors and laptops .. since that is min-width and device whose resolution is greater than that value should work

Comment: Could you maybe add me op skype so we can talk better?